# Resolver um bug no meio de um sprint?

Tags: scrum

É valido o usuário ter um bug que impede que seu trabalho continue ser reportado para o desenvolvimento e querer empenho em cima do novo bug e parar o desenvolvimento da plataforma?

Quando é válido adicionar esse bug ao próximo sprint?

O que é avaliado nessa decisão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O tamanho do estrago que o *bug* causa determina a urgência.

Supondo que seja uma aplicação que esta rodando e sendo utilizada pelos usuários e que esse *bug*, de alguma forma, impede que os usuários possam utilizar o sistema - em alguma *main feature* - é razoável que o desenvolvimento pare as outras features e foque em resolver essa situação. Imagino o estrago que seria para o seu cliente, se os usuários começarem a reclamar.

Caso esse *bug* seja em uma *feature* não muito utilizada, algo no *backoffice*, por exemplo, talvez seja negociável o momento em que o *bug* será resolvido e você poderia movê-lo para o próximo *sprint*.

Se o sistema não está no ar, o *bug* não está causando um problema real e, talvez, tenha sido descoberto durante os testes, o que não causará nenhum dano. Creio que esse possa ser facilmente colocado mais para frente.

Esses são exemplos e sugestões, não é você deve tomar essas decisões sozinho, é sempre o *Product Owner* que tem a palavra final. Você deve ajudá-lo a avaliar a situação, deixando claro que essa correção pode tomar o tempo de outra *feature*, possivelmente mais valiosa. Se ainda ainda sim ele decidir que o *bug* deve ser tratado com prioridade, é isso que deve ser feito.

Answer (score 0):

O objetivo traçado na "sprint planning" não muda em função do aparecimento de bugs, ou seja, todos continuarão trabalhando para liquidar o backlog daquela sprint.

Durante a "Daily Scrum" a equipe de desenvolvimento informará ao "Scrum Master" sobre este bug e sua gravidade. O "Scrum Master" por sua vez apresentará o fato ao "Product Owner".

O "Product Owner" fará seu julgamento quanto ao valor gerado ou perdido no produto ou na entrega em função do bug e definirá a correção do mesmo colocando-o no backlog na ordem/prioridade necessária.